# Sabotaging or hijacking someone else's unpopular question by editing

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

Imagine I have an idea for a question. I find that someone else had a similar idea long ago but it was of low quality and attracted few answers.

I can't submit my infinitely superior (!!!) version because it would be duplication.

What would be the implications of:

(a) Sabotaging the old question by editing, i.e. Editing its title and contents so that they were unrecognisable as a duplicate. Now I can submit my own.  (Note: I have no intention of ever doing this!)

(b) Hijacking the old question and 'improving' the title and body of the question with wholesale edits to make it precisely what  mine would have been.

Comment: It's only a duplicate if the other question has upvoted answers... if it doesn't then it's not a dupe.

Answer (score 6):

Is your problem the fact that an existing, possibly low quality, question is about your problem, but none of the answers apply to your situation?

Or is the problem that an existing question is similar, but not the same and thus not applicable to your specific problem?

If the latter, reference the existing the question and **explain why yours is different.** Point out the differences, and no, that doesn't mean you can just say "mine is infinitely superior!!!". What about the old question makes it not about your problem? With a computer question, *for example*, maybe the existing one asks for a Mac OS X solution but you need one that works on FreeBSD and none of the offered ones do?

If the former, you can always edit to fix up the question *without changing the original poster's intent* and then **offer a bounty on the question** to draw attention to it. Any user can propose edits, and valid edits (which do not change the intent of the question) are usually accepted.

In neither case will a contribution of yours be closed as a duplicate (unless you either fail to explain why your question is different, or there is another question which actually matches yours; in the latter case, at least you showed us that you tried to find an answer on your own first, which is usually a good thing in either case).

Remember, it's only a duplicate (basic rule of thumb here) if any answer to one question is equally valid as an answer to the other.

Answer (score 1):

The basics of a dupe are:
"Does the other question answer my question, or even if not currently, could additional answer(s) on the other question *potentially* answer my question".

If you answer yes to the above, you *shouldn't* post the "duplicate".
Of course, some scenarios are not as black and white, but generally this is the rule.

If your question is not a dupe, then just post it. Let people decide if dupe or not, and if closed as a dupe and you disagree with the reasons, edit and explain why.
This is how the site is designed, and for the most part works pretty well :)

Don't just presume because something is similar or "potentially" going to be a dupe that *therefore* community will close it as such.
Community voting in review may well identify the same dupe potential as you did, but also, like you did, they may see why it's not "quite" a dupe.

---

> a) Sabotaging the old question by editing, i.e. Editing its title and
> contents so that they were unrecognisable as a duplicate. Now I can
> submit my own. (Note: I have no intention of ever doing this!)
>
> (b) Hijacking the old question and 'improving' the title and body of
> the question with wholesale edits to make it precisely what mine would
> have been.

You (surely) already know this is not acceptable behaviour, so why ask?

Both of these options are terrible scenarios, and users doing this are (quite bluntly) users I would rather not see on the sites, to be honest.
Community moderation and actions should be for the community as a whole, not personal gains.
If we all did things based on personal gain, what sort of place would this be?  I'd find the most viewed and popular question (so viewed and linked to a lot of places), edit it and plonk *my* question in there.

This would be a terrible place.

There should never be any personal motives. The motives and reasons to edit any questions or answer should only ever be for improvements.